# NP to P transition

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, np

Are there any recent (feel free to add the "old" ones too) problems that were perceived as NP and then later someone came up with a  solution that is Polynomial? I think studying those cases would help in developing a knack of critical problem solving along with practicing competitive programming.

Comment: This is off-topic here. Stack Overflow stays focused on pragmatic code-related questions, not computer science theory. Try [Quora](http://quora.com).

Comment: Maybe http://cs.stackexchange.com would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of such problems is that of deciding whether a given integer is prime. PRIMES IS IN P is the famous paper that broke this news in 2002, to almost everyone's surprise.
I think that you will find this [link](https://www.quora.com/What-problems-were-once-thought-to-be-NP-complete-but-later-turned-out-to-be-in-P) helpful.